# circular network graph layout using python

Tags: plotly, python-3.5, igraph

I would like to make a graph with one vertex in the centre and many other vertices around it in circular formation, connected by edges.

I found nice example with plotly, but there is not such circular formation.

https://plot.ly/python/igraph-networkx-comparison/

Comment: Do you mean that you want to replicate the graph with the Kamada-Kawai layout?

Comment: Yes, it worked this way.